# Search a string in a file, then print the lines that start with that string

Tags: linux, bash

I have an assignment and I have no idea when it comes to managing files, reading and writing. Here's my main problem:

I have a script that manages a address book, at the moment the menu is finished, functions are being used but I don't know how to search or write a file.

The first "option" gives the user the option (duh!) to search the address book by the contact name. The pattern I want to use is something along the lines of "name:address:email:phone", letting the user to put Spaces in the name, address but not email nor phone, and only numbers in the last one. I believe I could achieve this with Regular Expressions, which I understand a bit from Java lessons.

How can I do this, then? I know `grep` may be useful, but I don' know of the parameters even after reading the man pages. Parsing line by line could be done with `for line in $(file)` but still not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowed to use `grep`, then you probably may use `awk`, and that's what I would prefer for most parts of your assignment.

Looking up a contact by name:

```
awk -v name="Anton Kovalenko" -F: '$1==name' "$file"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
grep "^something" $file | while read line 
do 
    echo $line;   #do whatever you want with your $line here
done
```

Comment: No `cat` is needed. You can `grep '^Something' file`. Also, the `$(file)` is probably wrong.